# How to send email from Windows Mobile 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, email, windows-mobile, windows-phone

i am trying to create a simple email sending application for windows phone in visual studio 2008, so please tell me which classes or methods do i have to use.

i tried this but it didn't work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;


      try
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            // setup mail message
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(textBox1.Text);
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(textBox2.Text));
            message.Subject = textBox3.Text;
            message.Body = textBox5.Text;

            // setup mail client
            SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox1.Text, textBox4.Text);
            mailClient.Send(message);

            MessageBox.Show("Sent");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'MailMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   2   The type or namespace name 'MailMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'MailAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   4   The type or namespace name 'MailAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   5   The type or namespace name 'SmtpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   6   The type or namespace name 'SmtpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   7   The type or namespace name 'SmtpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   8   The type or namespace name 'SmtpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: You can take out `Application.DoEvents();` - It doesn't do anything anyway except make you feel safe.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Compact framework doesn't support System.Net.Mail or System.Web.Mail. You can use an extension such as http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/7e16eccb-dc9e-4559-c79c-cfaad631ac15.htm or call out to a service that will send the e-mail on your behalf.

Comment: my code worked for windows form application but it's not working for windows phone application. is windows phone application doesn't System.Net.Mail or System.Web.Mail.

Comment: Are you using Windows Phone or Windows Mobile? They are two very different platforms. Windows Mobile uses the .NET Compact Framework which is a subset of functionality ported from the .NET Framework you'd be using for your Winforms applicaton.

Comment: ok i didn't know about that, i am asking about windows mobile

Answer (score 0):

To send mail etc on windows mobile you have to start a VisualStudio C#/VB SmartDevice Project.

Mail etc can be accessed via the namespace microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook. You have to add a reference to your Windows Mobile 5 (or higher) SDK directory containing the WindowsMobile assemblies.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.aspx

Here is a bare snippet without the needed stuff to first open a poom account etc.:

http://cjcraft.com/blog/2008/10/02/how-to-open-a-mail-in-inbox-using-pocket-outlook/